# Thickness of concrete wall for deck construction

Tags: concrete, deck, concrete-block, rebar

TL;DR: What thickness of a concrete wall underneath a deck should I go for? Is there any rule of thumb how to determine it?

---

I am planning to build a deck next to my house. The house is in a mild hill so the deck needs to be elevated a little. The plan is to build it from lost formwork concrete bricks *(I don't know how popular lost formwork is in other countries - below is an illustrative image of a wall build from it. It consists of hollow concrete bricks stacked on top of each other, filled with more concrete and reinforced using rebar.)*.

[image: Illustrative image of lost formwork]

In my country there are several thicknesses of the concrete bricks available - from 15 to 50 cm. E.g., the outer wall of the foundation of my house is built from the 30s. The other two dimensions are usually 50 cm (length) and 25 cm (height).

**I am struggling to find any information which would help me decide the thickness I need for the deck.** I want it to be robust, but at the same time I don't want to waste money on the concrete.

The image below contains the front view of the deck (replace "patio" with "deck" in the image) as it will be built. As I stated above, the house is in a mild hill, but the deck will be built on a flat surface since the area where the deck will be was flattened during construction of the house.

[image: Front view of the planned patio]

However, when the deck is finished it will be partially covered by the terrain of the garden. So most of the concrete will be under the surface and only the right side will stick out a bit (approx. half the height, maybe even less). The resulting front view will look like this (again, replace "patio" with "deck"):

[image: Front view with terrain]

**The way I want to construct the deck:**

- Concrete foundation in the ground. Approx. 30-50 cm thick and deep, depending on the used lost formwork brick thickness for the rest of the deck
- Lost formwork wall built on the foundation, filled with concrete, reinforced with rebar. Forming 3 sides of the deck (the 4th side is the house).
- I will fill the inside of the deck with coarse gravel or recycled concrete (lower layer).
- The upper layer of the inside of the deck (up to the top of the wall, approx. 20 cm layer), I will fill with finer gravel and pack it flat.
- The deck surface will be made of wooden planks placed on decking supports (shown below). The supports will sit on the packed fine gravel or concrete tiles/slabs (depending on the manufacturer recommendation). I do not plan to pour any concrete on top of the gravel.

[image: Decking support]

- The resulting concrete structure (without the wooden surface) will look something like this [image: Concrete patio with gravel]

---

**My question is:** What thickness of lost formwork bricks should I use?

Thickness 30 seems like an overkill - if these bricks can support my house, it seems to be a waste to use them to support a deck with wooden floor, some furniture and maybe 20 people at maximum.

I would like to go with 15 since they will be quick and cheap to fill up with concrete and rebar. But I am afraid that the weight/pressure/force of the packed gravel could cause too much trouble to it (cracks, etc.), especially to the right side of the deck, which will not be burried under the ground.

**What thickness should I use? Is there any rule of thumb how to determine it?**

Comment: Sounds like you're making a grade level deck, not a patio.

Comment: @Huesmann Sorry, my English vocabulary in the construction/building field needs a bit of improvement. Yes, it should most likely say "deck", not a "patio"

Comment: Any of the available sizes will hold up the deck. The answer comes down to the stability you need in a retaining wall. If it's only two blocks high it won't matter much.

Comment: I am guestimating about the filling of the deck. The beams are the load-bearing structure. Should the beam supports rest on concrete point foundations, the filling could be just some light aggregate, and minimize the pressure on the retaining wall. Should you not need the filling, you won't need any retaining wall at all, just a facade.

Comment: As long as the fill is compacted properly (95% MDD) it should be able to hold up pretty much anything.